# iisnode hang issue

Tags: node.js, iisnode

I am presently using node 0.8 with iisnode 0.1.21.

I have set nodeProcessCountPerApplication="4"  in the web.config under the iisnode tag.

My application starts perfectly with 4 node processes but it hangs after some time. It does not crash.

I observed that this happens once any one of the processes starts using more than 200mb of memory. Does any body know if this is a memory issue or is it something else?

Furthermore if i shutdown/endtask any one of the processes from the task manager, every thing starts working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Does the same app work correctly when self-hosted outside IIS? This behavior could occur if you end up blocking the event loop in the node.exe processes. The processes using up 200MB each sounds makes me think you are doing something out of the ordinary.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I'm using IISnode 0.1.21 x64 on Windows 2008 R2 and Node 0.8

My application is running successfully with 4 threads. But after sometime (say 3-4 hours) the responses don't make it from IISnode to the client and the user doesn't get the data on the page (but the rest of the application is working). I tried creating a log in the IISnode folder but didn't get anything from there.

If I remove even one node.exe process from the task manager, the application starts working properly. Then again after a couple of hours, i'm back to square one. (contd....)

Comment: (...contd)

I got the ETW log and this is what it shows:

<Data>{00000000-0000-0000-6E02-0080000000CA}: iisnode failed to process http response status line</Data>

<Data>{00000000-0000-0000-6E02-0080000000CA}: iisnode request processing failed for reasons unrecognized by iisnode</Data>